# jqChart from trirand - asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, jqchart

anyone have any experience with JQchart?
[JQChart](http://www.trirand.net/demochartaspnet.aspx)
The demo's on the site are all hard coded, i would love to find some examples or tutrials where the data is loaded dynamically from a database.

jqgrid rocks, so i'd expect the same from their charts

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They have examples on their site which show how to load it on a page in the code behind. These methods can easily be transformed to load the info dynamically [asp.net demo](http://www.trirand.net/demochartaspnet.aspx)

Comment: after digging through each demo i found 2, they are the more exotic scatter type and area charts. not the plain jane type of bar or pie, but i suppose i can just try translate it back. thanks

Comment: They also have documentation for webforms which explains it even more clearly: http://www.trirand.net/documentation/aspnet/index.htm , look at the populating with data chapter..

Comment: thats the grid, i am looking for the chart